# Getting error message "Error in checkFunc(Func2, times, y, rho) : Model function must return a list"

Tags: r

I am working on a model to predict the incidence of an infectious disease and have a model for it which was functioning well till yesterday. Now I get the message:

```
Error in checkFunc(Func2, times, y, rho) : 
  Model function must return a list
```

Here is the code:

```
library(deSolve)

run.model <- function(years,parameters,initial.state){

    years.needed = c(min(years)-1, years)
    results = ode(y=as.numeric(initial.state),
                  times=years.needed,
                  func=dx.model,
                  parms=parameters)

    rv = list()

    rv$parameters = parameters
    rv$years = years

    rv$results = process.ode.results(results, years)
    rv

}
sim = run.model(years=1500:2020,
          parameters=make.parameters(log.trate.hiv.neg.slope = log(1), 
                                     log.trate.hiv.neg.intercept = log(7),
                                     early.progression.risk.immune=0.00485*4.5,
                                     late.progression.risk.immune = 0.0005*4.5,
                                     latent.duration = 5,
                                     treat.tb.rate = 0.6,
                                     primary.progression.in.immune = .014),

                    initial.state = init.state)
```

I have no idea why I am getting this error.

Comment: where is the error occuring? You can use `traceback()` to get more detailed error messages

Comment: You haven't shown us `init.state`, so your code isn't reproducible.  It's hard to help you without reproducible code.

Comment: Where does the function `make.parameters` come from ? Silly proposal, have you tried ading `return(rv)` at the end of the run_model function ?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states: The model function must return a list.

This means your function `dx.model()` should return a list. The **?ode** help file says:

"The return value of func should be a list, whose first element is a vector containing the derivatives of y with respect to time, and whose next elements are global values that are required at each point in times. The derivatives must be specified in the same order as the state variables y."

Unfortunately, your example is not complete and reproducible so we cannot check the details and get it your code running.

Comment: Hi folks thanks for the responses and apologies for the delay. Was stuck at an airport. I think I understand what you are trying to say. I will try to modify as per suggestions and if it still does not work, I will post the other parameters to get an answer. Thanks a lot.